# HTTP STATUS 404, requested resource is not available. What mistake am I doing? Tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

My servlet application is

```
package p1;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyServ extends GenericServlet{
 public void init(ServletConfig con){
    System.out.println("INIT");
 }

 public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException{
    PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
    pw.println("HELLO");
    pw.close();
 }
}
```

and my web. xml file is

```
<web-app>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>sai</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>p1.MyServ</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>sai</servlet-nsame>
  <url-pattern>/abc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have pasted my WEB-INF folder into the webapp folder of tomcat 6.0. The WEB-INF folder has classes and web.xml file. classes folder has the package of my java program. When I try to run my servlet in the browser it shows

HTTP Status 404 -
type Status report
message description The requested resource is not available.

Whats the mistake i am doing?

Comment: What URL are you trying to hit? Tomcat conf? Try tailing the access-log, that'll usually give you an idea of what you've done wrong.

Comment: Tried URL is a must for this kind of question.

Comment: yea thats what I did..http://localhost:2020/FirstApp/abc

Answer (score 1):

You must restart the server to apply web.xml changes. Make sure you have restarted the server.

Answer (score 1):

don't copy WEB-INF in webapp forder. Create separate application folder, for example, `test` and copy WEB-INT in `test` Your servlet will be available on URL

```
http://localhost:<port>/test/abc

<TOMCAT_HOME>
 |-webapps
    |-manager
    |-data
    |-docs
    |-host-manager
    |-ROOT
    |_test <--- create this folser
      |-WEB-INF
         |-classes <--classes 
         |-lib <-- librares
         |-web.xml
```

Also you can copy it in ROOT, in that case your servlet will be available on URL

```
http://localhost:<port>/abc
```

Comment: +1 I missed the *WEB-INF copy* line, this is the right approach. Ideally should have build a war or copied an exploded version of war.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question related to project structure in eclipse ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395834/strange-web-app-structure-class-files-inside-web-inf-folder Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should paste to webapp/FirstApp folder.
So Tomcat could provide the context for your application.

Answer (score 0):

first check whether your tomcat sever is started by typing localhost:2020 if you get your tomcat page then its started