# Mapping context path to servlet class in server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, war

I used eclipse and developed an application which calls servlet `doPost()` method using `AJAX` call in `Javascript` and `jQuery`. It was working correctly in `eclipse` but when I tried copy these files to different server and run through browser I got `404 error`. This is because my ajax could not map the url to servlet class. Because in eclipse I had `web.xml` in which I configured the context path but I don't know how I can set this mapping in the server.

Comment: What server are you using? Did you just copied/pasted the files or you deployed the application using a war file?

Comment: Somewhat duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106213/http-status-404-requested-resource-is-not-available-what-mistake-am-i-doing-t/17106490

Comment: @Luiggi  - Its our college server by name omega. I just copied files and pasted in server.

Comment: I mean if you're using Tomcat application server or a Java EE application server like GlassFish, JBoss, Oracle WebLogic, IBM WebSphere or another. Note that omega looks like the hostname of the server, which is not related to the answer. Also, to deploy a Java web application you should export your application in form of war file.

Comment: @Luiggi - I think its Apache. Because in the response message I am getting server as apache. Please let me know How to deploy application as war file.

Comment: *Please let me know How to deploy application as war file* I guess you can search that on the net...

Comment: @Luiggi Thank you very much. I will go through that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some tutorials on how to deploy an application on server using WAR file. Hence I was able to deploy it in tomcat server. I have not tried to deploy it in other server. But as for the Tomcat server it worked fine.

Thank you for your help regarding this.